# flipfluid side of the fluid not showing up

Tags: animation, particles

[image]I'm trying to do waves, I experimented a lot with parameters whether I didn't know exactly  each was doing, after 1 week just lost the side of the fluid, I don't know what did I do wrong to make that happen.I can'T see then my fluid like I was underwater neither. any help on this one please? [image]

Comment: pls provide blend file because you didn't provide any useful information as parameters/settings etc

Comment: sorry , I posted  more infos thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot of the settings, it looks like the **FLIP Fluid Surface > Remove Mesh Near Boundary** option is what is causing the issue. When this option is enabled, the simulator will remove the sides of the liquid mesh that are touching the domain boundary.

To fix the issue, disable this option and re-bake the simulation.

Hope this info helps!

Comment: ooooh , that's it, I didnt even notice I checked this parameter, thank you so much , looks obvious  now, thank you for helping!